# Necessary conditions for Eigenspace Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Under what conditions can you not decompose a vector space into a direct sum of eigenspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the minimal polynomial does not factor into a product of pairwise distinct linear factors (Thanks to @JeppeStigNielsen for providing the correct wording here).

So for example, if $m(x)=x(x+1)$ we can find an eigenspace decomposition, but if $m(x)=x^2(x+1)$ we can't. Also you must be able to factor the minimum polynomial completely, i.e. it should not be irreducible, eg if $m(x)=x^2+1$ and the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$, then eigenspace decomposition is not possible.

Comment: (edited) So "when the minimal polynomial does not factor into a product of pairwise distinct linear factors".

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes, thank you, you are right...

Answer (score 1):

If we have
$$E=\bigoplus_{k=1}^r\ker(f-\lambda_k\rm{id})$$
so by taking a basis adapted to this decomposition we see that a matrix of $f$ in this basis is diagonal hence we see easily that a necessary and sufficient to this decomposition is that $f$ is diagonalizable.